# Having trouble building gcc (libiberty obstack.c won't compile)

Tags: linux, make, gcc, cmake, autoconf

I'm running openSUSE 11.4, which is kinda old, so I'm trying to build some updated dependencies for another thing I want to build.

I've downloaded the source for `gcc-6.4.0` (also tried the latest - didn't work).

I'm running `../gcc-6.4.0/configure --prefix=/usr2/aakhavan/local --disable-multilib --enable-languages=c,c++ --disable-bootstrap --disable-libmpx --with-system-zlib`

using

```
gcc-build>gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
Target: x86_64-suse-linux
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --infodir=/usr/share/info --mandir=/usr/share/man --libdir=/usr/lib64 --libexecdir=/usr/lib64 --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,fortran,obj-c++,java,ada --enable-checking=release --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.3 --enable-ssp --disable-libssp --with-bugurl=http://bugs.opensuse.org/ --with-pkgversion='SUSE Linux' --disable-libgcj --disable-libmudflap --with-slibdir=/lib64 --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --enable-libstdcxx-allocator=new --disable-libstdcxx-pch --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --program-suffix=-4.3 --enable-linux-futex --without-system-libunwind --with-cpu=generic --build=x86_64-suse-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.3.4 [gcc-4_3-branch revision 152973] (SUSE Linux)
```

the `make` fails with this:

```
gcc -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -I/usr2/aakhavan/local/src/gcc-chain/local/include -I. -I../../../gcc-6.4.0/libiberty/../include  -W -Wall -Wwrite-strings -Wc++-compat -Wstrict-prototypes -pedantic  -D_GNU_SOURCE ../../../gcc-6.4.0/libiberty/physmem.c -o physmem.o
In file included from ../../../gcc-6.4.0/libiberty/partition.c:27:
/usr2/aakhavan/local/src/gcc-chain/local/include/stdlib.h:424: warning: ISO C90 does not support ‘long long’
In file included from ../../../gcc-6.4.0/libiberty/partition.c:27:
/usr2/aakhavan/local/src/gcc-chain/local/include/stdlib.h:521:1: warning: C++ style comments are not allowed in ISO C90
/usr2/aakhavan/local/src/gcc-chain/local/include/stdlib.h:521:1: warning: (this will be reported only once per input file)
In file included from ../../../gcc-6.4.0/libiberty/obstack.c:63:
/usr2/aakhavan/local/src/gcc-chain/local/include/stdlib.h:424: warning: ISO C90 does not support ‘long long’
In file included from ../../../gcc-6.4.0/libiberty/obstack.c:63:
/usr2/aakhavan/local/src/gcc-chain/local/include/stdlib.h:521:1: warning: C++ style comments are not allowed in ISO C90
/usr2/aakhavan/local/src/gcc-chain/local/include/stdlib.h:521:1: warning: (this will be reported only once per input file)
../../../gcc-6.4.0/libiberty/obstack.c: In function ‘call_chunkfun’:
../../../gcc-6.4.0/libiberty/obstack.c:92: error: request for member ‘extra’ in something not a structure or union
../../../gcc-6.4.0/libiberty/obstack.c:94: error: request for member ‘plain’ in something not a structure or union
../../../gcc-6.4.0/libiberty/obstack.c: In function ‘call_freefun’:
../../../gcc-6.4.0/libiberty/obstack.c:101: error: request for member ‘extra’ in something not a structure or union
../../../gcc-6.4.0/libiberty/obstack.c:103: error: request for member ‘plain’ in something not a structure or union
../../../gcc-6.4.0/libiberty/obstack.c: At top level:
../../../gcc-6.4.0/libiberty/obstack.c:115: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘_OBSTACK_SIZE_T’
../../../gcc-6.4.0/libiberty/obstack.c:115: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘_OBSTACK_SIZE_T’
../../../gcc-6.4.0/libiberty/obstack.c: In function ‘_obstack_begin_worker’:
../../../gcc-6.4.0/libiberty/obstack.c:119: error: ‘alignment’ undeclared (first use in this function)
../../../gcc-6.4.0/libiberty/obstack.c:119: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
../../../gcc-6.4.0/libiberty/obstack.c:119: error: for each function it appears in.)
../../../gcc-6.4.0/libiberty/obstack.c:121: error: ‘size’ undeclared (first use in this function)
../../../gcc-6.4.0/libiberty/obstack.c: At top level:
../../../gcc-6.4.0/libiberty/obstack.c:157: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘_OBSTACK_SIZE_T’
../../../gcc-6.4.0/libiberty/obstack.c:157: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘_OBSTACK_SIZE_T’
../../../gcc-6.4.0/libiberty/obstack.c:156: error: conflicting types for ‘_obstack_begin’
/usr2/aakhavan/local/src/gcc-chain/local/include/obstack.h:183: error: previous declaration of ‘_obstack_begin’ was here
../../../gcc-6.4.0/libiberty/obstack.c: In function ‘_obstack_begin’:
../../../gcc-6.4.0/libiberty/obstack.c:161: error: request for member ‘plain’ in something not a structure or union
../../../gcc-6.4.0/libiberty/obstack.c:162: error: request for member ‘plain’ in something not a structure or union
../../../gcc-6.4.0/libiberty/obstack.c:164: error: ‘size’ undeclared (first use in this function)
../../../gcc-6.4.0/libiberty/obstack.c:164: error: ‘alignment’ undeclared (first use in this function)
../../../gcc-6.4.0/libiberty/obstack.c:164: error: too many arguments to function ‘_obstack_begin_worker’
../../../gcc-6.4.0/libiberty/obstack.c: At top level:
../../../gcc-6.4.0/libiberty/obstack.c:169: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘_OBSTACK_SIZE_T’
../../../gcc-6.4.0/libiberty/obstack.c:169: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘_OBSTACK_SIZE_T’
../../../gcc-6.4.0/libiberty/obstack.c:168: error: conflicting types for ‘_obstack_begin_1’
/usr2/aakhavan/local/src/gcc-chain/local/include/obstack.h:185: error: previous declaration of ‘_obstack_begin_1’ was here
../../../gcc-6.4.0/libiberty/obstack.c: In function ‘_obstack_begin_1’:
../../../gcc-6.4.0/libiberty/obstack.c:174: error: request for member ‘extra’ in something not a structure or union
../../../gcc-6.4.0/libiberty/obstack.c:175: error: request for member ‘extra’ in something not a structure or union
../../../gcc-6.4.0/libiberty/obstack.c:178: error: ‘size’ undeclared (first use in this function)
../../../gcc-6.4.0/libiberty/obstack.c:178: error: ‘alignment’ undeclared (first use in this function)
../../../gcc-6.4.0/libiberty/obstack.c:178: error: too many arguments to function ‘_obstack_begin_worker’
../../../gcc-6.4.0/libiberty/obstack.c: At top level:
../../../gcc-6.4.0/libiberty/obstack.c:188: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘_OBSTACK_SIZE_T’
../../../gcc-6.4.0/libiberty/obstack.c:188: error: conflicting types for ‘_obstack_newchunk’
/usr2/aakhavan/local/src/gcc-chain/local/include/obstack.h:182: error: previous declaration of ‘_obstack_newchunk’ was here
../../../gcc-6.4.0/libiberty/obstack.c: In function ‘_obstack_newchunk’:
../../../gcc-6.4.0/libiberty/obstack.c:196: error: ‘length’ undeclared (first use in this function)
../../../gcc-6.4.0/libiberty/obstack.c:201: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned
../../../gcc-6.4.0/libiberty/obstack.c: At top level:
../../../gcc-6.4.0/libiberty/obstack.c:298: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘_obstack_memory_used’
make[2]: *** [obstack.o] Error 1
```

I've tried disabling libiberty, but then it complains about building libtools. Searched around online but couldn't find any answers. What the heck is going on?

Answer (score 1):

From the errors in your compile of
[obstack.c](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libiberty/obstack.c),
it is obvious that you don't have the right environment to build gcc-6.4.0.

I note that gcc can be installed by the command:

```
sudo zypper install gcc
```

And that you can find the package
[gcc6-6.5.0+r265524-2.1.x86_64.rpm](http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/gcc/SLE-11/x86_64/gcc6-6.5.0+r265524-2.1.x86_64.rpm)
in the repository of
[download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/gcc/SLE-11/x86_64/](http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/gcc/SLE-11/x86_64/),
without the need to compile anything.

In fact, it is extremely difficult to duplicate the exact environment in which
an old package was originally compiled. It is much easier and less time-consuming
to find a release version of it. Because glibc is truly
[backward-compatible](https://superuser.com/a/1450958/8672),
this will work even if glibc in your environment is newer,
so even if you cannot compile that program any more because your header files
are not of the right version.

Comment: Maybe your answer will work too for the topic started, however I have no package manager on my system, so i really need to (cross) compile GCC. Maybe the linker is using the system header files instead of the package header files. I don't know how i can find out.

Comment: I'm not on openSUSE. I'm just trying to compile GCC and get the same errors about obstack as the person who opened the issue.

Comment: @Flip then you can open a different question with your specific environment details.

Comment: I could have posted a separate question. But i haven't and the bounty can't be transferred AFAIK. If you want the bounty, then read the actual bounty which tells you (briefly but detailed enough) which platform i'm on and how i'm compiling instead of suggesting tools that i don't have. And again ... the original question is about compiling which is the same as my question.

Comment: @harrymc alright i deleted most of them. Thx for the efforts anyway

Comment: One small try: [Install ipkg package manager](http://rescene.wikidot.com/synology-ipkg), then perhaps you could install [gcc_4.2.1-5_i686.ipk](http://ipkg.nslu2-linux.org/feeds/optware/syno-i686/cross/unstable/).

Comment: i like to have the latest gcc. I know about ipkg repo

Comment: The latest gcc on an old system will take some doing.