# Linux packages naming

Tags: linux, apt

In Linux, why are there packages named like for example libavcodec56, libavcodec57, libavcodec58? To be more clear, why is there not a single package libavcodec with version 56, 57, 58 like many other packages? Why are they entirely new packages?

Comment: These represent major releases. Some previously installed software will depend on the old versions and may require at least a recompile.

Answer (score 3):

Most distributions only allow one version of package `xyz` to be installed at a time. If `libxyz` is a library, where incompatible versions 1 and 2 are in use at the same time, they can't just call the packages `libxyz-1` and `libxyz-2`, installing the later will delete the former. Thus some other naming scheme is needed so you can have `libxyz1-1.5` (upstream 1.5) and `libxyz2-2.1` (upstream 2.1) installed at the same time. This obviously requires further distinctions at the individual file names of the contents of the package, but that is another kettle of fish.

Comment: I see. Package libavcodec58 on my system installs a file "libavcodec.so.58.91.100". As I understand, .so files are libraries, similar to Windows DLL. My question then would be, could libavcodec (I'm using it just as example) be implemented in backward compatible manner, to have only one libavcodec.so, where each new version contains all functions from previous version and possibly adds new ones, so that applications can use it without recompiling?

Answer (score 1):

Linux has a mechanism for versioning that does not require
renaming of the package.
It is used for `glibc`, as you can see in the post
[How exactly a system might break by updating glibc?](https://superuser.com/questions/1450027/how-exactly-a-system-might-break-by-updating-glibc).

But this requires lots of work on the part of the developers,
mainly in that `glibc` must backward support all the previous
versions of all its functions.

Not many developers can guarantee to support all their
software, present and past, or to invest the same level of
development time as is invested in `glibc`.

Packages like `libavcodec56`, `libavcodec57` etc. do not
guarantee backward support, and versions might not be
entirely compatible, so programs that use them might need
to be modified when changing versions.
The fact that the version names are different is the best
indicator of that, and this is done by design.